# required type Uri found Uri?

Tags: android, kotlin, uri

I get an error message:

```
required type Uri 
found Uri?
```

My code:
val  imageUri = data?.data
val imageStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(imageUri)
val selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream)
profile_page_pimage.setImageBitmap(selectedImage)

[This is error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWY3X.png)

Answer (score 3):

`data?.data` resolves to either a `Uri` or `null`. Kotlin treats `null` as being part of the type system, so the inferred type is `Uri?` (`?` indicating that the value might be `null`). However, `openInputStream()` does not support `null`. So, you need to check to see if `imageUri` is `null` and, if it is, do not try to use it.

For example, you could use a safe call (`?.`) with `let()`:

```kotlin
data?.data?.let { imageUri ->
  val imageStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(imageUri)
  val selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream)
  profile_page_pimage.setImageBitmap(selectedImage)
}
```

Now, if you did not get a `Uri` from `data?.data`, you will not crash when trying to read in the non-existent content.

Comment: I tried but now I get  this error   `filePath.putFile(imageUri).continueWithTask {task ->
                    if (!task.isSuccessful) task.exception?.let { throw it }
                    filePath.downloadUrl`     unresolved reference  imageUri

Comment: @Kürşat: That would need to be inside the `let()` function call, along with anything else that refers to `imageUri`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the null-safety mark !! , so your code you should be like ths

`val imageStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(imageUri!!)`

Comment: If `imageUri` is `null`, this will crash the app.

Comment: i guess it won't because there is null safety ?  in data?.data , so in this case i guess it won't crash because the null safety mark ? will prevent the app from crash even if the value is null

Comment: No. `!!` says "ignore the fact that this may be `null` and try using it anyway". And, if it is `null`, this will lead to a `NullPointerException`. Use `!!` only when you are *absolutely certain* that it cannot be `null`. Otherwise, do something else that can safely deal with the possibility of `null`.

Comment: Alright , i could be wrong , i just looked at it like if imageUri returns null safety like in data?.data , something like this var imageUri : Uri? = data?.data

Comment: Yes, but `imageUri` could be `null`. The point behind `?` is to indicate that a value might be `null`. So, you need to handle `null` safely. `!!` is the opposite of handling `null` safely.

Comment: [not-null assertion operator (`!!`)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#the--operator) is null-prone, will throw `kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException` if the imageUri is null. It is same as not handling the null in java (i.e. using the variable without null checks).